# How to combine conditions taking different parts of an object as parameter in react.js for CSS

Tags: reactjs, api, object, conditional-statements, classname

I have search in other topics but couldn't find what I needed.
In a group project in React I have to render a background-color according to properties in an object which is itself in an API.

Values of 2 different properties must be controlled but we only manage in one by isolating the last word of this value (exemple below in the code of the jsx file of our component):

```
const Profile = () => {
const params = useParams();
const [infoProfile, setInfoProfile] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    Axios
    .get(`https://a.nacapi.com/sainstgram.users?id=${params.id}`)
    .then((response) => {
        setInfoProfile(response.data[0])});
    }, [params.id])

function getCategory () {
    if (infoProfile.category){
        return infoProfile.category.split("'").pop().split(" ").pop()
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

return (
    <div className={`Profile ${getCategory()}`}>  
        <CardProfile infoProfile={infoProfile} />
        <PostList className="PostList-profile" id={parseInt(params.id)}/>
    </div>
)
}
```

I must control condition also for infoProfile.name because the value for some profile of category is null so I have to control the name.

I tried to put another function getName on the same principle using includes and using it as className but it didn't worked out.

Can you give me a hint or another way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the other condition that you need to check for like `infoProfile.name` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one function to create your className by checking first for the `category` and second for the `name`.

```
function getClassName () {
    if (infoProfile.category) {
        return infoProfile.category.split("'").pop().split(" ").pop()
    } else if (infoProfile.name) {
        return infoProfile.name // plus anything else you need to do to the name
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

For bonus points, memoize the value of your className using react's `useMemo` hook so this does not have to run on every render. [More info.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#:%7E:text=suggests%20a%20fix.-,useMemo,-const%20memoizedValue%20%3D%20useMemo)

```
const profileClass = useMemo(() => {
    if (infoProfile.category) {
        return infoProfile.category.split("'").pop().split(" ").pop()
    } else if (infoProfile.name) {
        return infoProfile.name // plus anything else you need to do to the name
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}, [infoProfile])
...
<div className={`Profile ${profileClass}`}>
```